# How to copy data from harddrive to time capsule over USB connection via OSX terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, time-capsule, copy-paste

I want to copy a big amount of data from a harddrive to a time capsule controlled drive.so I put the harddrive via USB to the capsule and connect to the capsule server with a Mac. But when I then move the data to a folder on the time capsule drive by drag&drop it seems to me that the copying goes over WIFI instead of the directest USB data connection way. This takes aeons! Isn't there a way to tell the capsule server to copy the data over their USB connection? thnx!
(I asked the same [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881332/how-to-copy-data-from-harddrive-to-time-capsule-over-usb-connection-via-osx-term), but maybe this is the right place for this kind of question?)

Comment: Asking twice is rarely advisable, please add at least a link to the other question. Regarding your issue: what makes you think that the copy is done via WiFi instead of USB? Did you turn of your WiFi to verify?

Comment: no but the speed tells me.

Comment: That's an assumption, not a prove. Turn WiFi off to verify.

Comment: good point. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the data flow is "drive -> TC -> Mac -> TC", using the same USB wire both ways. If you want to speed it up, connect the harddrive directly to the Mac.

Comment: time capsule has its own server. couldn't I just make the server copy the files by itself?

Comment: No, it can't (as you've found out)

Comment: looks like you're right. besides the design, apple sucks most of the time when it comes to proffessional usage... thnx!